# Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ be any twice differentiable function satisfying $f(ax+(1-a)y)\leq af(x)+(1-a)f(y)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ be any twice differentiable function satisfying $f(ax+(1-a)y)\leq af(x)+(1-a)f(y)\;\forall x,y\in[0,1]$ and any $a\in[0,1]$. Then for all $x\in[0,1]\;, f"(x)\geq0$.

here f is convex function, it means $f"(x)\geq0$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is twice differentiable, we have
$$f''(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - 2f(x) + f(x-h)}{h^2}$$

By convexity with $a = \frac{1}{2}$, we have
$$f(x+h) + f(x-h) \geq 2f(x)$$

which implies
$$f''(x) \geq 0$$